# How to hide element on a specific class in jquery

Tags: jquery

i look for a solution that hides me an element on a specific class.

```
<div class="employeeStatus" class="panel-body status-1">
  <p>Mark</p>
  <p class="isHereSince">08:15</p>
</div>
<div class="employeeStatus" class="panel-body status-10">
  <p>Ben</p>
  <p class="isHereSince">10:01</p>
</div>
<div class="employeeStatus" class="panel-body status-2">
  <p>Jon</p>
  <p class="isHereSince">06:58</p>
</div>
```

if the there is a status-10 just hide the `<p>` element with the `class=isHereSince`

I have tried something like this:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  if($(".employeeStatus").hasClass('status-10')) {
    $('.isHereSince').hide();
  }
});
```

but it's not working. Do i have to iterate over the div elements ?

Comment: First you are not supposed to have 2 classes. Second no double quotes for document. Then you can use this shorter version $('status-10 p').hide();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have multiple `class=""` on the same element, and when that is fixed just use `$(".employeeStatus.status-10 .isHereSince").hide()`

```
<div class="employeeStatus panel-body status-10">
  <p>Ben</p>
  <p class="isHereSince">10:01</p>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".employeeStatus.status-10 .isHereSince").hide()
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".employeeStatus.status-10 .isHereSince").hide()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="employeeStatus" class="panel-body status-1">
  <p>Mark</p>
  <p class="isHereSince">08:15</p>
</div>
<div class="employeeStatus panel-body status-10">
  <p>Ben</p>
  <p class="isHereSince">10:01</p>
</div>
<div class="employeeStatus panel-body status-2">
  <p>Jon</p>
  <p class="isHereSince">06:58</p>
</div>
if the there is a status-10 just hide the
<p> element with the class=isHereSince I have tried something like this:
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan fixed, didnt noticed that the op had written document in `""`

Comment: @GregOstry No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your selectors:

```
$(".employeeStatus.status-10 .isHereSince").hide();
```

would be enough. And maybe you will need to combine multiple `class` attributes to one.

Answer (score 0):

As there is multiple class `isHereSince`, so you need to hide it's inner `p` tag. And also you don't need to use `hasClass`.

And Fix your html. You have multiple class attribute on element.

```
<div class="employeeStatus panel-body status-1">
  <p>Mark</p>
  <p class="isHereSince">08:15</p>
</div>
<div class="employeeStatus panel-body status-10">
  <p>Ben</p>
  <p class="isHereSince">10:011</p>
</div>
<div class="employeeStatus panel-body status-2">
  <p>Jon</p>
  <p class="isHereSince">06:58</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.employeeStatus.status-10 .isHereSince').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1:- Can't use multiple class.
2:- Use children method of jquery to find next class.

HTML

```
<div class="employeeStatus panel-body status-1">
  <p>Mark</p>
  <p class="isHereSince">08:15</p>
</div>
<div class="employeeStatus panel-body status-10">
  <p>Ben</p>
  <p class="isHereSince">10:01</p>
</div>
<div class="employeeStatus panel-body status-2" >
  <p>Jon</p>
  <p class="isHereSince">06:58</p>
</div>
```

Js

> $(document).ready(function() {
>   $('.status-10').children('.isHereSince').hide(); });